# When $\sigma\in S_n$ belongs to the Galois group of a separable polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, permutations, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld, and let $f(x) ∈ F[x]$ be a polynomial with only simple roots. Let $E$ be a splitting ﬁeld for $f(x)$. Consider the Galois group $G_f$ of the polynomial $f(x)$.

Now I need to prove $G_f$ is the set of permutations $σ ∈ S_n$ that  take every $F$-algebraic relation between the roots of $f(x)$ to another $F$-algebraic relation between the roots.

That is: I need to show that:

> A permutation $σ ∈ S_n$ comes from an automorphism in $Gal(E/F)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\forall g(x_1,...,x_n) ∈ F[x_1,...,x_n] )(g(α_1,...,α_n) = 0\Rightarrow g(α_{σ(1)},...,α_{σ(n)}) = 0)$.

(Here $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are all the roots of $f(x)$).

I am considering the following track for one direction:

We have a unique $F$-algebra homomorphism $ψ: F[x_1,...,x_n] → E$ defined by: $x_i \mapsto α_i$.

For $σ ∈ S_n$. Let $σ'$ denote the unique automorphism of the $F$-algebra $F[x_1,...,x_n]$ defined by $x_i \mapsto x_{σ(i)}$.

Take the composition $ψ ◦ σ'$. It is a homomorphism $ϕ: F[x_1,...,x_n] → E$. Using the universal property of quotients, may be we can prove that there is an automorphism $σ_0 ∈ Gal(E/F)$ such that $ψ ◦  σ' = σ_0 ◦ ψ$ and we also have that the permutation of the roots of $f(x)$ induced by $σ_0$ is actually the same as our original permutation $σ$.

And then I am a bit confused. So may I please ask for a way if we can acutally do it? And also how to deal with the other direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K =F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ be the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f \in F[x]$ whose roots are $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$. We have an isomorphism 
$$\varphi : F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I \to K, \qquad \varphi(p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+I)=  p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$$ where $I$ is the ideal $$I = \{ p \in F[x_1,\ldots,x_n], p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) = 0\}$$

**If and only if** $\sigma \in Gal(K/F)$, we have that $\sigma$ induces an automorphism of $K$ permutating the $\alpha_i$, so that $\varphi^{-1}\circ\sigma \circ\varphi$ induces an automorphism of $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ permuting the $x_i$.

Comment: It makes sense to me... But how does this lead to an anwer to the question? May I please ask for some more explicit explaination to the last sentence? How does it related to the original question?

Comment: @PropositionX  Your question is about those automorphisms of $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ permuting the $x_i$ **and** fixing $I$, ie. about the automorphisms of $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ permuting the $x_i$.

Comment: MayI I please ask why the map $\phi$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Why is the evaluation map to the splitting field surjective?

Comment: @PropositionX The map $\varphi : F[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to F[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n]= K$, $\varphi(p(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=  p(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ is a surjective ring morphim

Comment: @PropositionX $I$ is the kernel of this ring morphism, therefore $\varphi$ is also an isomorphism $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I \to K$

Comment: But why $F[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$?

Comment: @PropositionX Because the $\alpha_j$ are algebraic. You know that $F[\alpha_1] \cong F[x]/(f(x))$ ?

Comment: I know that it is algebraic, but how can it applied to multivariable case? how can it be proceed inductively?

Comment: @PropositionX In the same way. $F[\alpha_1,\alpha_2] = F[\alpha_1](\alpha_2) = F(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2) = F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$. Otherwise take any $b \in F[\alpha_1,\alpha_2] $ and note there is a $F$-linear dependence between the powers of $b$, ie $b^{-1} = \sum_{m=0}^d c_m b^m \in F[\alpha_1,\alpha_2] $

Comment: @PropositionX Also if $\sigma \in Aut(K/F)$ then $b$ and $\sigma(b)$ have the same minimal polynomial over $F$, therefore $\sigma$ acts as a permutation on the roots of $f$